# Weird text in RichTextBox c#

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I need to do something like paint, the only differ, you can draw on screen. When user click on a tool (pen, line, rect, text etc.) I take screenshot of the screen and put it as background image for a second full screen form. Then by handling mouse events draw on it. Im trying to follow MS Paint and draw text using third form with a RichTextBox inside it. This form must be transparent, and after I'll take new screenshot and load as background of second form.

This is code for third form which is transparent.

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TransparencyKey = Color.Turquoise;
this.BackColor = Color.Turquoise;
richTextBox1.BackColor = this.BackColor;
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see, text is being light blue. This is my problem.

Comment: Windows forms and transparency doesn't mix very well. Maybe try to write directly in the third form instead of using a RichTextBox,but i won't bet on it,I really wish you luck

Comment: @Pikoh probably I'll do so... Thanks.

Comment: Also: when using TransparencyKey it will only work for the __one exact color__. You text seems to have  anti-aliased pixels of many semi-transparent colors. You can prevent anti-aliased pixels when you drawstring but I doubt you can do it inside a RTB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way how to fix that, and I decided to use label instead. By handling key press event and making label back color transparent I got expected result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wr52.png)